# get a list of predictions of a neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

I created a neural network to classify messages. Now I want to collect the predictions into a list in python. How do I do this?

So here is the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(500, activation = "relu", input_shape=(7600,)))
# Hidden - Layers
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(300, activation = "relu"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation = "relu"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4, noise_shape=None, seed=None))

model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation = "softmax"))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=['accuracy'])



model.fit( np.array(vectorized_training), np.array(y_train_neralnet),
          batch_size=2000,
          epochs=3,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(np.array(vectorized_validation), np.array(y_validation_neralnet)))
```

Here I tried to print the shape of validation_data that is inside of the model.fit() method but it gives an error.

```
NameError: name 'validation_data' is not defined
```

Comment: Is this all of your code? you can't print `validation_data` because you haven't defined `validation_data` anywhere. `validation_data` is a keyword argument for `model.fit`.

Comment: i didn't define validation_data, but suppose i did it before model.fit(), can i then access the predictions inside of validation_data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
preds = model.predict(X_test)
```